# Ruby CGI using JQuery fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to use the fadeIn/fadeOut effect with jQuery in my Ruby cgi code.

But for some reason it isn't working.

My ruby cgi code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby -w

require 'cgi'
cgi = CGI.new
puts "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

puts <<HEREDOC
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Ruby Lab</title>
</head>
<body>                                                                            
HEREDOC

puts <<HEREDOC

HEREDOC

fullname = cgi['fullname']
address = cgi['address']
phone = cgi['phone']
if (fullname != "" && phone != "")
  puts "This is the valid information you've entered: <br /><br />"
  puts "Fullname: " + fullname + "<br />"
        puts "Address: " + address + "<br />"
  puts "Phone #: "
  puts '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>'
  puts '<script type="text/javascript">';   
  puts "var jphone = '" + phone + "';";
    puts <<HEREDOC
   var jphonearr = jphone.split("-");   
  document.write("(" + jphonearr[0] + ") ");
  document.write(jphonearr[1] + "-" + jphonearr[2] + "<br /><hr />");
  $('jphonearr[0]').hide().fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800); 
  $('jphonearr[1]').hide().fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800); 
  $('jphonearr[2]').hide().fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800); 

HEREDOC
  puts '</script>';
end

puts <<HEREDOC
HEREDOC


puts <<HEREDOC
</body>
</html>
HEREDOC
```

I'm trying to fade in the different parts of the phone number at different time.

This is the jQuery part in the code above:

```
 $('jphonearr[0]').hide().fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800); 
  $('jphonearr[1]').hide().fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000); 
  $('jphonearr[2]').hide().fadeIn(1200).delay(3000).fadeOut(1200);
```

It doesn't fade in nor fade out.

Many thanks!

Edit: Page source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Ruby Lab</title>
</head>
<body>                                                                            

This is the valid information you've entered: <br /><br />
Fullname: Hello<br />
Address: Hi<br />
Phone #: 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jphone = '343-343-3434';
   var jphonearr = jphone.split("-");   
  document.write("(" + jphonearr[0] + ") ");
  document.write(jphonearr[1] + "-" + jphonearr[2] + "<br /><hr />");
  $('jphonearr[0]').hide().fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800); 
  $('jphonearr[1]').hide().fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800); 
  $('jphonearr[2]').hide().fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800); 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nope nothing, its blank

Comment: I can see it in the page source, the phone number I entered gets store in jphone and looks something like this var jphone = '544-454-4584

Comment: I have added the page source in the question

Comment: Edit: i have re added it since I was making some changes, this source above is original one

Comment: before doing it as cgi... I suggest you try running the above html code just in your actual browser (save it as an html page and open it with your browser). Then you can look at the javascript console for errors and try doing things like typing `$('jphonearr[0]')` and seeing what it outputs... then try typing `$('jphonearr[0]').hide()` and see what happens. etc etc.